# BLE scanning and read value from pc, how can i solve 'unknown data' issue?

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, dataformat, segger-jlink

I'm a beginner in c#, I'd appreciate your help.
Here's what I use:
-nRF52840 dk (it is developed by segger embedded studio)
-pc bluetooth (window 10)
Im trying to create a program that scans Ble and receives a value(continuously sent by ble). I have been looking at the Windows-universal-samples.
but when i try to read value, it doesn't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLUQd.png)

How can i solve this problem? Thank you for reading it, and if you know how, please share it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to get help, you will to add the relevant source code to your question. It is also not obvious to me if the problem is more likely in the nRF5280 code or in the C# code. It would be helpful it you could determine that and the focus on one side only.

Comment: my ble code use uint_8 and uwp sample code use uint_32. How can i solve that? just change code? Is it possible?

Comment: What are we supposed to do with this random piece of information from many lines of source code that we have never seen?

Answer (score 0):

The LED Characteristic (0x1525) appears to be controlling LED 3 for the [nordic_blinky](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.sdk5.v15.0.0%2Fble_sdk_app_blinky.html) example. My thought is that this might be a write only characteristic and so that is maybe why you are getting the error.

As others have pointed out, it is difficult to know with the little information you have shared. A link to the sample code you are following would be a helpful start.

Also, have you tested the nordic_blinky with general tools? For example, in chrome you can go to the URL:  `chrome://bluetooth-internals/#devices`. It will tell you if the characteristic is readable and writable. Being able to share that would be useful information for others to help. If you are able to read or write in Chrome, then we can be more confident the issue is with your code. Again sharing it working in Chrome and your code that is failing will be helpful for others to assist as to where the issue might be.

Try these experiments and update the question would be my suggestion.